# How to add a:hover rule in js function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I modified some jQuery slide gallery for my website. And I want to add `.nav li a:hover{color:#00f;}` in css, but it didn't work. I checked it in firebug, the css rule is be crossed off. I find something in the jquery slide galley's js file,like this:

```
function init(){
    g.find(".nav").children("li").css("margin","0").css("padding","5px"); 
    g.find(".nav").children("li").children("a").css("text-decoration","none").css("display","block");   
}
```

Is it should be add the a:hover css rule in the js files? How to add it? Thanks.

Comment: If the CSS rule is crossed out, that means that it is overridden by another CSS rule. You have to find out where the overriding takes place - which is not in the above code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in JS with

```
g.find(".nav").children("li").children("a").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#00f');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#000');
    }
);
```

You could also modify the plugin stylesheet so you wouldn't have to override it.

Comment: @Ed Why not just `g.find(".nav > li > a")`

Comment: Because. That was the original example, so I used that. There are 100s of different ways to do things.

Comment: @Ed Not really. Maybe a couple. However, when posting an answer, consider refactoring the code in order to make it more simple, more efficient, more readable, etc. That is always appreciated. You are more likely to get upvotes if you optimize the code.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes a mess after a while, but you can give CSS directives precedence over subsequent directives using [`!important`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm).

```
.nav li a:hover{ color:#00f !important; }
```

Since you mention the property being crossed off in firebug, I suspect this is your issue.

Comment: @Frode Using !important would be harmful for the OP because he doesn't even know which CSS rule he has to override.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Out of curiosity (and not because I'm a die hard fan of !important :-) ), what do you mean? If the jQuery JS overrides his CSS by setting inline style directives, how else can he make sure his CSS isn't overridden?

Comment: @Frode How do you know that it's the jQuery code that overrides it? Maybe it's the CSS source code from the plug-in CSS file. The point is that the OP has to find you what overrides his original CSS rule. Only then he can move on and use a good solution. For example, if it's the CSS code from the plug-in, he can just comment out that CSS rule...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: True, good point - thanks! But if you change the framework/plugin, surely the guy in the next cubicle will wonder why his list items don't have the standard hover effect in his part of the application :-) For small things like this, I usually favor extending/overriding the framework/plugin I'm using, instead of forking it. So I would do `.aSpecificPartOfTheApplication .nav li a:hover{ color:#00f; }` (possibly with !important if I can't include my CSS last, or the JS sets inline directives).

Comment: @Frode The point I'm trying to make is that the OP **must understand** the issue first. He must know what is causing the override. Once he understands the situation, he can then find a good solution - and using !important is one of the possible solutions. But if you suggest him to use !important without knowing the source, that can be harmful to him because he then has 2 layers of overrides without understanding the first layer. The idea is to first understand the issue, and then find a good solution. Thankfully, SO has a commenting system - that way you can ask the OP to elaborate the issue.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Ah, I see. I thought you meant that the JS method was less harmful than !important in that respect. Cheers.